# Is there a name for putting the IP address as a subdomain?

Tags: dns

I've seen a couple of networks where domain names are self descriptive of the IP address they resolve to. For example, `ip-1-2-3-4.example.com.` would resolve to 1.2.3.4. The DNS server appears to parse the subdomain to determine the IP address, instead of using a static lookup table.

I'm trying to determine which DNS servers support this approach, for more documentation and discussions of this approach, but am struggling to know what other people call it. Is there a name for this sort of self descriptive domain name?

So far, I'm aware of [CoreDNS support](https://coredns.io/plugins/template/)) for this concept, although it's only documented under Resolve multiple ip patterns.

```
. {
    forward . 8.8.8.8

    template IN A example {
      match "^ip-(?P<a>10)-(?P<b>[0-9]*)-(?P<c>[0-9]*)-(?P<d>[0-9]*)[.]dc[.]example[.]$"
      match "^(?P<a>[0-9]*)[.](?P<b>[0-9]*)[.](?P<c>[0-9]*)[.](?P<d>[0-9]*)[.]ext[.]example[.]$"
      answer "{{ .Name }} 60 IN A {{ .Group.a}}.{{ .Group.b }}.{{ .Group.c }}.{{ .Group.d }}"
      fallthrough
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t think any plain old DNS server would support this, because it’s such a niche use case. It’s just… lazy.

Answer (score 0):

It is either just an A record or CNAME in DNS.  There is nothing fancy going on here.  They probably have a script that creates a DNS entry from the IP address of the subdomain.